# What are the major flaws and limitations of this hash-based stream cipher design?

Tags: hash, protocol-design, stream-cipher

- `K` is a 224-bit key.
- `C` is a 32-bit counter; it is publicly known. the same value is never used twice.
- `plaintext` has arbitrary length (up to 64kB).
- `H` is a cryptographic hash function that returns `len(plaintext)` bits.
- `^` is the bitwise XOR.
- `+` is the concatenation.

Encryption:

`ciphertext = plaintext  ^ H(K + C)`

Decryption:

`plaintext  = ciphertext ^ H(K + C)`

- Are there any fundamental flaws?
- Would it make sense to use a longer key?
- Under what circumstances would doing `H(C + K + C)` instead of `H(K + C)` make the algorithm more secure?
- I intend to use **Skein**, which comes in three flavors of internal state sizes: 256, 512 and 1024 bits. How does the internal state size limit the strength of the whole system? Would it make any sense to use the 512/1024 bit variants, even though `len(K+C) = 256`?
- Is there anything particular about Skein that would make it unsuitable for the job?

**edit**: Thinking about it, `len(K) > internal state size` seems pointless. To break the encryption,  an attacker would just need to find a `K` that produces the same internal state as the real `K`.

Comment: To turn your question on its head, what are the advantages? In what way do existing, well-cryptanalyzed ciphers fall short of your needs, and in what way does this improve upon those shortcomings?

Comment: More to the point, why should anyone bother to examine this cipher in the first place?

Comment: It's mostly out of scientific interest: I was searching for a cipher to encrypt a UDP stream, and found AES CTR. Then I thought, _well certainly hashing before XORing would only increase security_. Then I thought, _maybe hashing alone will suffice?_. Then I noticed that this would allow me to encrypt variable-length messages easily.

Comment: Why would hashing before XORing necessarily increase security? Using your gut intuition when dealing with cryptography is usually a bad idea — unless you can *prove* an assertion, you should not assume it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any fundamental flaws?

The construction itself is secure for a good H. It's close to what many stream ciphers use internally. E.g. chacha has an H that hashes a 256-bit key, a 64-bit nonce and a 64-bit counter to get 512 bits of output.

> Would it make sense to use a longer key?

Yes, if you want more brute force resistance, since finding *a* preimage is not enough to find the key, if it leads to different values for other counter values.

> Under what circumstances would doing H(C + K + C) instead of H(K + C) make the algorithm more secure?

If your H was vulnerable to length extension attack (e.g. SHA-256) and the counter was variable length, H(K + C) would not be secure, but H(C + K + C) might. However, with a constant sized C, I can't think of a reason to use H(C + K + C).

> I intend to use Skein, [...]

Then shouldn't you use the stream cipher construction from the [Skein paper](https://www.schneier.com/skein.pdf) (pdf, section 4.10)?

Comment: Excellent hint; thanks! I didn't know that Skein supports efficient partial result determination.

Answer (score 2):

> …limitations of this hash-based stream cipher design?

One of the limitations of this hash-based stream cipher design would be that it does not offer any kind of *“authentication”*, nor any kind of *“integrity-protection”*.

Maybe you just forgot to describe how you will be handling authentication and integrity-protection, but it’s important not to forget about it.

> I intend to use Skein…

That raises the question why you aren’t simply using [Threefish](https://www.schneier.com/threefish.html) as a well-vetted block cipher. After all, [the design of Skein is based on the Threefish tweakable block cipher](https://www.schneier.com/skein.html)!

In the unlikely case you really need a stream-cipher because something prevents you from using a block-cipher, you could create one based on Threefish, which is bound to provide a bit more speed (when implemented correctly) than building a cipher based upon the Skein Hash Function Family.

**Nota Bene:**

As it’s not clear to me why someone would try to create a hash-based stream cipher while well-analyzed stream ciphers are available, I have skipped cryptanalysis – which means that your design may (or may not) have security issues I did not check on. In the end, I guess [I somewhat chime in with Stephens comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16351/what-are-the-major-flaws-and-limitations-of-this-hash-based-stream-cipher-design/16363#comment35925_16351) and simply don’t seem to have [that “scientific interest” you mentioned in your comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16351/what-are-the-major-flaws-and-limitations-of-this-hash-based-stream-cipher-design/16363#comment35932_16351).

Comment: The peers authenticate to a trusted third party, and receive `K` from that third party, via TLS. The plaintext contains a `CRC-32` checksum to detect ciphertext manipulation.

Comment: @mic_e That process does not authenticate the *ciphertext*. Just because a plaintext cannot be easily recovered from a ciphertext does not imply that it can't be manipulated in a way to have predictable effects on the ciphertext. Particularly with a XOR-based cipher, where flipping a bit in the ciphertext flips the exact same bit in the plaintext.